# VB.NET syntax highlight problems using hightlight.js in blog

Tags: vb.net, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I use hightlight.js for syntax highlighting in my blog and it works fine for C# and Java. But i have problems with highlight for VB.NET code. Most of keywords and comments not highlighted.

For example:

```
Public Enum EditorBrowsableState
    Always    ' Отображается всегда
    Never     ' Не отображается
    Advanced  ' Отображается во складке "Все"
End Enum
```

result [here](http://tezaurismosis.blogspot.ru/2014/07/blog-post.html) (i use `<pre><code class="vb">` as always) (excuse me, i can't now add sample image)

How can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old and the author apparently stopped using highlight.js in his blog so I even don't know this is the cause. but I'm introducing what made vb codes not highlighted in **my case**.

It's just because the CDN library I used didn't include VB to begin with.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

It only covers apache, bash, zsh, CoffeeScript, C++, C, C#, CSS, Diff, Http, Ini, Java, JSP, JavaScript, JSON, Makefile, Mak, Xml, Markdown, Nginx, Objective-C, Perl, Nginx Conf, PHP, Ruby, Python, Gemspec and so on. If we need something else, we should load the module for it.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/languages/vbnet.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was used script tag with correct path to js file for vb.net in my page - highlight worked, but in strange way... I read script with highlight, but don't find the problem. So, I will try again